# Android root folder read access

Tags: android, qt5, root

I need read folders inside root Android file system. All Android file managers can do this without "rooting" device. But in my case I got strange result.

Application is written using Qt5/C++. It is not new app but old enough.  Permissions for access to media are granted by READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in AndroidMainfest.xml and by dynamic request. Application opened /mnt folder to allow user locate music files on it. But on some devices external SD card is not mounted to /mnt. Therefore I want change app to allow user read root / folder and allow find music on it. Following code:

```
    QTreeView* tv = new QTreeView(this);
    QFileSystemModel* fsm = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    tv->setModel( fsm );
1:    tv->setRootIndex( fsm->setRootPath( "//mnt/" ) ); // Android & Linux Ok
2:   //tv->setRootIndex( fsm->setRootPath( QDir::rootPath() ) ); // Linux Ok, Android not
```

Works fine in Android and desktop Linux. But if comment line after label 1: and uncomment line after label 2: - then code will work only in Linux. It will give in tree view all files and directories inside root "/" directory. But in Android it will give empty result. Nothing. This does not relate to Qt5 - this is an Android issue. QDir::rootPath() == "/".

Anybody knows what is needed to allow application read root directory in Android?

Comment: It requires rooting the device. I would not assume that you will be able to access `/mnt` either on many devices. And, you are losing filesystem-level access to most of external storage on Android Q (by default) and R+ (for all apps).

Comment: If it "requires root" - then HOW many file managers work WITHOUT rooting?

Comment: Pre-installed file managers from the device manufacturer get permission to work with arbitrary locations from the device manufacturer. Ordinary apps are limited to what is world-readable, and there is less and less of that with each passing year. `/` is not among those locations. `/mnt` may not be among those locations on all devices, as that lies outside the bounds of the Android SDK, and therefore device manufacturers can do what they want regarding permissions on that directory.

Comment: Not only preinstalled FMs can read root folder. Root File Explorer can do this on non-rooted devices.

Comment: I have no idea what "Root File Explorer" is. If you mean [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer), [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx.rr), [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clearvisions.explorer), or [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree), they say they need root. If you mean [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acr.rootfilemanager), the comments suggests that it needs root.

Comment: The first one. It requires root access for "write" operations outside user's directory. But it reads all file system as well. And not only this app can do same. Here is link to screenshot of root folder made with Android Total Commander. The device is not rooted. https://i.imgur.com/DMDwKjs.png

Comment: Ok may I not read root folder. But what about /storage folder instead? I cannot read it too. The /mnt I can open and read all it's content, but in /storage I can see only one folders level inside it. In attempt read any of these folders including /storage/emulated I get empty content. But Total Commander reads /storage/emulated and down on tree without problem. On the same non-rooted device. May be there is special permission to allow read it? I do not need write, only read.